# when i run program it is printing 126 infinite times, how ch will take value 126?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
 {
   char ch;
   while(ch>125)
   {
       printf("%d, ",ch);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format this mess! Take the [tour], read [ask].

Comment: You wrote this, right? So, what do you *expect* this code to do? I.e. what value did you *expect* `ch` to have that would avoid entering that infinite loop, and more importantly, *why* do you expect that? `ch` has indeterminate value. as such, comparing against determinate content and expecting determinate results is somewhat madness.

Comment: Why do you ignore or not enable compiler warnings? Every modern compiler will warn about what you do. Pay heed to them!

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized ch, so it can be anything each time you run your program, in this case it was 126

Comment: That's one thing that **might** happen, but not the answer.

Comment: Not initializing ch to any definite value, is the reason, its holding a garbage value
Garbage can be anything, in this case it is 126, if the  program is run again that garbage value can again be different.

Comment: You want to do research what _**undefined** behaviour_ means!

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer, 'it can be anything' implies undefined behavior

Comment: No, just getting a different value each time is not the same as UB!